# SSRS Bad Results

Tags: reporting-services

I have a simple matrix that is returning the wrong results in rendering. I have tried rebuilding the project and deleting the rdl.data file for the report.

I am using a shared data source to set the parameters. I have verified the actual data returned is correct. I verified the datasource that sets the parameters is also returning the correct results

The code is basic

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER
    ,COMPANY_CODE 
    ,SUM(CONVERTED_AMOUNT) AS CONVERTED_AMOUNT 
FROM aTable <br />
WHERE  COMPANY_CODE IN ('ABC', 'EDF', 'JKL') 
AND (ACCOUNT_NUMBER = '12020000') AND 
(@PrePostCommit = 'Post' AND CAL_ACCTG_PERIOD <= @EndPeriod OR 
 @PrePostCommit = 'Pre' AND CAL_ACCTG_PERIOD <= @PreEndPeriod) 
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER, COMPANY_CODE
```

I tried rebuilding the matrix, and the results are still wrong. The full report has multiple tables from different data sets and data sources.

Any suggestions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7twr.png)

Comment: can you add screen shots as to what you mean by wrong results please? Are you sure the datasource is pointing to the correct / desired server?

Comment: yes I am sure it is pointed to the correct data source.I use shared datasources for all of the matrixes. and I put the source in the footer of all my reports.

Comment: And all of my environments have shared data sources that point to dev, test and prod.

Comment: Are you able to share your report design and raw data as well? (screen shots)

Comment: @Tamera Were you able to resolve this issue? Did my answer help out?

Answer (score 0):

SSRS doesn't change your values so the issue is most likely either the query or the expressions in the report. I'm assuming your expressions are pretty straightforward like just checking a `Sum`.

Check this part of your `WHERE` clause:

```
(@PrePostCommit = 'Post' AND CAL_ACCTG_PERIOD <= @EndPeriod OR 
 @PrePostCommit = 'Pre' AND CAL_ACCTG_PERIOD <= @PreEndPeriod)
```

You are mixing `AND` and `OR` and are not going to get the intended behavior. You should use parentheses to specify the order of operations like so:

```
((@PrePostCommit = 'Post' AND CAL_ACCTG_PERIOD <= @EndPeriod) OR 
 (@PrePostCommit = 'Pre' AND CAL_ACCTG_PERIOD <= @PreEndPeriod))
```